# Please tell me what I am doing wrong for this multivariable Calculus Problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Suppose $F =(2x−4y)i +(x+3y)j$. Use Stokes' Theorem to make the following circulation calculations:
>
> (a) Find the circulation of $F$ around the circle $C$ of radius $10$ centered at the origin in the $xy$-plane, oriented clockwise as viewed from the positive $z$-axis.

Circulation = $\int_CF\cdot dr$

Here is my work: Please tell me the correct answer and what I am doing wrong:

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_C F\cdot dr&= \int\int_S \text{curl} F · dS & \text{by Stokes' Theorem} \\
&= \int\int\langle 0, 0, 5\rangle \cdot \langle 0, 0, 1\rangle~dA & \text{since the circle lies on }z = 0 \\
&= 5 * (\text{Area of }C) \\
&= 5 * 100π \\
&= 500π.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @MichaelRametta To learn how to use LaTex, just right click on any LaTex, go to show math as and click on tex commands to give you an idea of how to use Latex.

Comment: So does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: For the rim, $x$ and $y$ are OK, but $z=2$.

Comment: would part (b) be 8pi

Comment: @Michael Rametta: Regarding the original question you had here, I request that you re ask it with the proper TeX and formatting, as it will likely get a good answer that way.  The two questions were merged incorrectly, and I apologize for this.  (You still retain the reputation from the previous question)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I just made a simple miscalculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's correct except for the small issue of orientation. That changes the sign of your answer. Officially, you need $\vec n = \langle 0,0,-1\rangle$.

Comment: I see. Thanks a bunch A++

Answer (score 2):

In your first equation, you take the circulation to be the line integral of the dot product of the field with the differential of the position vector- what you are calculating is the flux of the field across the circle. In order to get the circulation, you need to instead take the dot product of the field with the differential length element of the circle, which is orthogonal to the position vector, along the tangents of the circle.